# difference between fortran pointers or allocatable arrays for c_f_pointer call

Tags: arrays, pointers, fortran, mpi

I'm currently working with mpi shared memory communicators. In examples I've seen, they allocate the shared memory and associate it to a pointer using the C_F_POINTER(cptr,fptr,shape) call. But I've recently noticed that if instead of a fortran pointer I use an allocatable array, everything works fine.

Some example code below, I've replaced declaring the array A(:,:) as an allocatable, instead of a pointer.

The only difference seems to be that now I can use the 'allocated(A)' call.

Is there any reason this should not work, or a reason I should use a pointer instead? or any other difference I should be aware about? I don't have much experience with Fortran pointersI would want this code to be portable.

```
program mpishm
USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY : C_PTR, C_F_POINTER
use mpi

implicit none

integer, parameter :: dp = KIND(1.0d0)
integer, parameter :: N =  16000

integer :: rank,isize,ierr
integer :: shmcomm,shmrank,shm_size

integer :: win !window
integer(KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: winsize
integer :: disp_unit
type(C_PTR) :: baseptr
!real(dp), POINTER :: A(:,:)
real(dp), allocatable :: A(:,:)
integer :: arrayshape(2)

arrayshape=(/ N,N /)

call mpi_init(ierr)
call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world,rank,ierr)
call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world,isize,ierr)

call mpi_comm_split_type(mpi_comm_world,MPI_COMM_TYPE_SHARED,0,MPI_INFO_NULL,shmcomm,ierr)
call mpi_comm_rank(shmcomm,shmrank,ierr)
call mpi_comm_size(shmcomm,shm_size,ierr)

call mpi_Barrier(mpi_comm_world,ierr)

if(shmrank==0)then !allocate all memory on root
 winsize=8_MPI_ADDRESS_KIND*N*N
else
 winsize=0_MPI_ADDRESS_KIND
end if
call mpi_win_allocate_shared(winsize,1,MPI_INFO_NULL,shmcomm,baseptr,win,ierr)

if(shmrank/=0)then
  call MPI_Win_shared_query(win,0,winsize,disp_unit,baseptr,ierr)
end if

!associate Fortran pointer with shared memory

call C_F_POINTER(baseptr, A, arrayshape)

write(rank+6,*)'allocated A?',allocated(A),size(A,1),size(A,2)
write(rank+6,*)'allocated A?',size(A,1),size(A,2)


call mpi_comm_free(shmcomm,ierr)
call mpi_finalize(ierr)

end program mpishm
```

Comment: The `fptr` argument of `c_f_pointer` should be a pointer.

Comment: I'm curious if the values in your array A are what you expect to find.

Comment: @MattP yes, so far it seems I can still fill in and access the array fine. I've done some testing with this sample code, as well as with a large code I work with.

Comment: Can you tell us what compiler and version manages to compile it with an allocatable array? Gfortran 4.8.5, 4.9.2 and 5.4.0 all fail, complaining that A must be a pointer in c_f_pointer. Intel 16.0.4 compiles it even with -stand f03, however, even though their documentation at https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/679090 says the code is not valid. Looks like a bug in the Intel compiler to me, as a prototype is in scope at the calling point, hence the illegal arguments should be diagnosed.

Comment: @IanBush I am using Intel 17.0.1.132 using -stand=f2008 checks. I didn't realize this could be a bug since everything still worked normally. I assumed it was because allocatables and pointers were closely related or something.

Comment: Allocatable arrays and pointers are very different things, I'm struggling to see why you think they might be the same thing. Further In my opinion this code is both incorrect, and incorrect in such a way that the compiler should fail to compile it. I would report it as a bug to Intel.

Comment: @IanBush Well, I didn't think they were the same thing, but I don't know how the memory is allocated in both cases behind the scenes. I assumed it was related since they both function with this call and I wanted to get a better understanding on how. Even if they're not related, I'd still be curious to know how this still worked. I only noticed this worked when I realized after several tests were already run that I'd forgotten to change the type in some other code.